# SQL Server : select last result from group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to retrieve the last result from 2 similar results (the oldest result)

```
FromUser | ToUser | Message | Date
User1    | User2  | hi      | 01/01/2013 20:00
User1    | User2  | hi later| 01/01/2013 21:00
User5    | User2  | hi      | 01/01/2013 20:01
User5    | User2  | hi later| 01/01/2013 21:01

SELECT        
    CM.FromUser, CM.ToUser, CM.Message, CM.Date, 
    U.UserId, U.UserFullName, U.UserName, U.UserPhoto
FROM
    ConversationMessages AS CM 
INNER JOIN
    Users AS U ON U.UserName = CM.FromUser
WHERE
    CM.ToUser = @user
ORDER BY 
    CM.Date DESC
```

it should list user 5 hi later first then user1 hi later second (user5 is newer by date). only last row basically grouped by `FromUser` then all ordered by date. I'm useless with sql, tried many suggestions on here and got none to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use window functions for this, rather than `group by`:

```
select FromUser, ToUser, Message, [Date], UserId, UserFullName, UserName, UserPhoto
from (SELECT CM.FromUser, CM.ToUser, CM.Message, CM.Date, U.UserId,
             U.UserFullName, U.UserName, U.UserPhoto,
             row_number() over (partition by CM.FromUser, CM.ToUser order by [Date] desc) as seqnum
      FROM ConversationMessages CM INNER JOIN
           Users U
           ON U.UserName = CM.FromUser
      WHERE  CM.ToUser = @user
     ) s
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY CM.Date DESC ;
```

Comment: amazing gordon, exacly what I needed thank you! i really need to learn more than basic sql considering how much i program :P

Comment: Gordon im having a prob please help, if the last message in a ground is from the fromuser it wont show , this is for a messaging app like facebooks

i need it to work like facebook messages, the returned username and userfullname is always from the ToUser but if the last message is from the fromuser then it will show the the message and date from the Fromuser but then the userfullname and username from touser, alternatively if its from the touser then this code works perfectly. Just need it to also show the fromusers as last but also grouped by  touser id's. Do you get that? hope u can help

Comment: saying that i explained that wrong, as if adam is logged in and last message was fromuser adam touser crazyguy it would show crazyguy username+fullname but adam message/date. if it was fromuser crazyguy , touser adam it would all be from crazyguy. works as conversations

Comment: @user is the logged in user

Comment: @user1311546 . . . I think that might be a different question.  Both answers interpret the question the same way, providing different methods for the solution.

Comment: it only shows the conversation if the last message in group was the other user than logged in user, if logged in user starts new conversation if doesn't show until other user responds :( should have said better in first post, needed it to act like facebook conversations

Comment: @user1311546 . . . Going from "exactly what I needed, thank you" to "should have said better in the first post" suggests that you should ask another question, more clearly defined for your situation.

Comment: re-marked, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752066/sql-group-by-acting-like-facebook-messaging-mssql-sp

Comment: its just it looked like it was, untill i added other conversations in and only some conversations showed as the logged in user was the last message. looks perfect if all conversations last message is from the other user

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard SQL you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM ConversationMessages cm1
LEFT JOIN ConversationMessages cm2
ON cm1.fromUser = cm2.fromUser AND cm1.date < cm2.date
WHERE cm2.date IS NULL AND cm1.toUser = 'User2'
ORDER BY cm1.date DESC
```

It should work in any DBMS. Of course, make sure you replace `User2` by the appropriate SQL Server variable.

Output:

```
FromUser | ToUser | Message | Date
User5    | User2  | hi later| 01/01/2013 21:01
User1    | User2  | hi later| 01/01/2013 21:00
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8aa2/1).